# ошибка построения проекта в spring data

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-jpa

**При построении проекта spring boot возникает ошибка**

```
Error:(48, 38) java: method findOne in interface org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryByExampleExecutor<T> cannot be applied to given types;
  required: org.springframework.data.domain.Example<S>
  found: java.lang.Long
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) S
    (argument mismatch; java.lang.Long cannot be converted to org.springframework.data.domain.Example<S>)
```

**Вот где ругается:**

```
@Service("jpaAccountService")
@Transactional
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService {

    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    ////....////
    @Override
    public Function<Long, Account> read() {
        return p -> accountRepository.findOne(p);//вот здесь ошибка
    }

}
```

**Я подозреваю, что проблема в pom файле.
вот pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>Study_project</groupId>
    <artifactId>laba_1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mustache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


</project>
```

Comment: Попробуй, для начала, разверни лямбду в анонимный класс...

Comment: ок, сделаю... так что за ошибка у меня в pom файле, почему не видит методы crudrepository?

Comment: метод findOne должен браться из crudrepository, но  вместо него берется какая-то дичь

Comment: Объявление `AccountRepository` покажите.

Comment: проблема была в версии... заработало

Comment: ошибки не будет, потому что я наследуюсь от crudrepository

Comment: Имею такую же проблему и так понял, что автор ее разрешил. Но как конкретно?

Comment: @ИванЦерулик проблема в pom файле, не совпадали версии